# aerender ERROR: No render settings template was found with the given name

Tags: after-effects

I'm trying to run aerender.exe from command-line using

```
aerender.exe -project /path/to/my/project -comp "Intro" -s 1 -e 10 -RStemplate "Multi-Machine Settings" -OMtemplate "Multi-Machine Sequence"
```

I actually copy/pasted this command and tweaked it slightly to fit my .aep file and composition name.

However, running it gives me

```
aerender ERROR: No render settings template was found with the given name.
```

I've tried running in admin mode to no avail.

I simply dont get it. They're default templates and even Adobe states them on their site [(https://helpx.adobe.com/after-effects/using/automated-rendering-network-rendering.html](https://helpx.adobe.com/after-effects/using/automated-rendering-network-rendering.html)).

Why do I get this error? 
Can anyone using after effects confirm this?

Comment: To be clear, you are changing the value `/path/to/my/project`, right? Are there spaces in your path?

Comment: Yep, leaving out the params -RStemplate and -OMtemplate with the corresponding options renders correctly.

Comment: no, no spaces included in the path.

Answer (score 0):

I found the problem!

I'm using a German version of After Effects CS6.

The template names are translated into German, too.

So the above command should look like:

```
aerender.exe -project /path/to/my/project -comp "Intro" -s 1 -e 10 -RStemplate "Multi-Machine Settings" -OMtemplate "Sequenz für mehrere Rechner"
```